# Translation algorithm for my app

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I just develop a basic English to Chavacano(Native language) Translator Application in android.

Well I already finish the string Tokenization wherein for every word that was tokenize , the app will select the corresponding equivalent in database.

To visualize it clearly, I'm going to explain it further using diagrams and codes.

DATABASE:

```
_id | english   | chavacano
1       I           yo
2       you         tú
3    I love you    ta ama yo contigo
```

Main Activity.java

```
DataBaseHelper myDatabaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

//Declared EditText
TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText4);
TextView view2 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText3);
enter code here

//First check if text input is phrase and store to String but if not return false

 myDatabaseHelper.openDatabase();
String preText = myDatabaseHelper.Translator(view2.getText().toString());
  myDatabaseHelper.closeDataBase();

//Check if bool is true , true if the text is translated but if false means there's no corresponding translation for it so do the String Tokenization

if(myDatabaseHelper.indicator==true{
 view.setText(preText.getText());
}

else if (myDatabaseHelper.indicator==false{
//Lets do the string tokenization
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(view2.getText().toString());
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                myDatabaseHelper.openDatabase();

                String text = myDatabaseHelper.translator(st.nextToken().toString()); //this is the method to query

                myDatabaseHelper.closeDataBase();


                    sb.append(text);
                    sb.append(" ");

            }
            view.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

Code for DatabaseHelper.java

```
boolean indicator=false;
public String translator(String answer) {

    String translated="x";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT chavacano FROM dictionary where english'"+answer+"'", null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{


            translated= c.getString(0);



        }while(c.moveToNext());
        indicator=false;
    }
    else{
        indicator=true;
        return answer;
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();

return translated;
}
```

So here we go, 
I could translate I love you into ta ama you contigo
But if i put another text into the phrase I love you. Like I love you Girl

It will be translated into " yo love tu girl "
And how could I get the " ta ama you contigo Girl" ?

What do you i need to do or what algorithm should I add to make this app more accurate? 
One of the thing that I'm also thinking is using Split string if the Text contains (AND, punctations marks) and so on

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use translator Apis which does lot better then what you made

its simple as below lines

```
GoogleAPI.setKey(/* Enter your API key here */);

String translatedText = Translate.DEFAULT.execute("Bonjour le monde", Language.FRENCH, Language.ENGLISH);
```

refer this link for android translator  [https://developers.google.com/translate/](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs)

a demo project link [See here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-api-translate-java/)

a complete example is there in this blog [http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/10/androidtranslate-using-google-translate.html](https://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/10/androidtranslate-using-google-translate.html)

Comment: As what I've said It's a native language. That language is not available on google tranlsate api. If it's available why would I made one. 
So I have to develop my own translation. Is there any solution in my problem? thank you

Answer (score 2):

As you have figured out for yourself, translating text by simply mapping words and phrases based on patterns or a lookup table does not give good results.

However, doing a decent job of translation is very difficult.  If you started from scratch (and a good text book) it would take you years of effort.

So a more practical approach is to either use the existing Google Translate integration, or investigate third party off-the-shelf alternatives ... for Android.

If this is a student project, then I would advise *finding* a good textbook and reading it.  Also, discuss with your project advisor how good is "good enough" ... because doing a really good job is most likely infeasible.

(There is no way that we can explain how to do language translation in a Stack Overflow answer.  The topic is way too big.)